# Model analyzing in Java 3D

Tags: java-3d

In Java3D application I have two planes. How can I find if they have an intersection and if they do what is the angle between these planes? And how to resolve the vector of their intersection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intersection between two planes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408670/intersection-between-two-planes)

Comment: no, i need to find the angle between these planes, not the line of intersection.