# Faster tetrahedron-tetrahedron intersection

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry, vectormath, tetrahedra

For one project of mine I require reliable detection of intersection between two tetrahedrons in 3D space. I do not need the points/lines/faces just to know if intersection is present or not. Touching is considered intersection too but common triangle face is not considered as intersection. After quite a struggle to achieve this as fast as possible my solution boiled to this horribility:

1. **let have tetrahedrons `v0,v1`**

   each tetrahedron has 4 triangles `t[4]` where each triangle has 3 points `p0,p1,p2` and normal vector `n`.
2. **compute planes of all 4 sides of both tetrahedrons**

   so any point `p` on plane is given by equation

   ```
   dot(p,n) + d = 0
   ```

   where `n` is normal of the plane. As that is known this boils to computing `d`

   ```
   D0[i] = -dot(v0.t[i].p0,v0.t[i].n)
   D1[i] = -dot(v1.t[i].p0,v1.t[i].n)
   i = { 0,1,2,3 }
   ```

   for each triangle of each tetrahedron
3. **test any combination of triangle vs triangle intersection between v0,v1**

   so just loop between all 16 combinations and use triangle vs triangle intersection.

The triangle `v0.t[i]` vs triangle `v1.t[j]` intersection boils down to this:

1. **compute intersection between planes**

   this is obviously ray (for non parallel planes) so simple cross product of the plane normals will give the ray direction

   ```
   dir = cross(v0.t[i].n,v1.t[j].n)
   ```

   now it is just matter of finding intersection point belonging to both planes. Exploiting determinant computation directly from the cross product of the normals the ray computation is like this:

   ```
   // determinants
   det=vector_len2(dir);
   d0=D0[i]/det;
   d1=D1[j]/det;
   // position
   pos = d0*cross(dir,v1.t[j].n) + d1*cross(v0.t[i].n,dir);
   ```

   for more info see:

   - [SO/SE: Line of intersection between two planes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32410473/2521214)
   - [Wolfram: Plane-Plane Intersection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane-PlaneIntersection.html)
2. **compile signed distance intervals of triangle ray intersection for each triangle**

   so simply compute intersection between ray and each edge line of triangle remembering min and max distance from `pos`. We do not need the actual point just the scalar distance from `pos` which is the parameter returned by line/ray intersection.
3. **check if ranges of both triangles overlaps or not**

   if overlaps than `v0,v1` intersect ... if no overlap occurs for all of the 16 tests than `v0,v1` does not intersect.

As you can see it is a lot of stuff to compute. My linear algebra and vector math knowledge is very limited to things I use so there is a high chance there might be much better approach for this. I tried a lot of things to ease up this without any luck (like using bbox,bsphere, using more simple test exploiting that both ray and triangle edges are on the same plane etc) but the result was either slower or even wrong (not counting edge cases correctly).

Here my actual **C++** implementation:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool tetrahedrons::intersect_lin_ray(double *a0,double *a1,double *b0,double *db,double &tb)
    {
    int i0,i1;
    double da[3],ta,q;
    vector_sub(da,a1,a0); ta=0.0; tb=0.0; i0=0; i1=1;
         if (fabs(da[i0])+fabs(db[i0])<=_zero) i0=2;
    else if (fabs(da[i1])+fabs(db[i1])<=_zero) i1=2;
    q=(da[i0]*db[i1])-(db[i0]*da[i1]);
    if (fabs(q)<=_zero) return 0;       // no intersection
    // intersection ta,tb parameters
    ta=divide(db[i0]*(a0[i1]-b0[i1])+db[i1]*(b0[i0]-a0[i0]),q);
    tb=divide(da[i0]*(a0[i1]-b0[i1])+da[i1]*(b0[i0]-a0[i0]),q);
    if ((ta<0.0)||(ta>1.0)) return 0;   // inside line check
    return 1;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool tetrahedrons::intersect_vol_vol(_vol4 &v0,_vol4 &v1)   // tetrahedron v0 intersect tetrahedron v1 ?
    {
    int i,j,_ti,_tj;
    _fac3 *f0,*f1;
    double pos[3],dir[3],p[3],det,D0[4],D1[4],d0,d1,t,ti0,ti1,tj0,tj1;
    // planes offset:  dot(p,v0.t[i].n)+D0[i] = 0  ,  dot(p,v1.t[j].n)+D1[j] = 0
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
        D0[i]=-vector_mul(pnt.pnt.dat+fac.dat[v0.t[i]].p0,fac.dat[v0.t[i]].n);
        D1[i]=-vector_mul(pnt.pnt.dat+fac.dat[v1.t[i]].p0,fac.dat[v1.t[i]].n);
        }
    // plane plane intersection -> ray
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
     for (j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
        f0=fac.dat+v0.t[i];
        f1=fac.dat+v1.t[j];
        // no common vertex
        if ((f0->p0==f1->p0)||(f0->p0==f1->p1)||(f0->p0==f1->p2)) continue;
        if ((f0->p1==f1->p0)||(f0->p1==f1->p1)||(f0->p1==f1->p2)) continue;
        if ((f0->p2==f1->p0)||(f0->p2==f1->p1)||(f0->p2==f1->p2)) continue;
        // direction
        vector_mul(dir,f0->n,f1->n);
        det=vector_len2(dir);
        if (fabs(det)<=_zero) continue; // parallel planes?
        d0=D0[i]/det;
        d1=D1[j]/det;
        // position
        vector_mul(p,dir,f1->n); vector_mul(pos,p,d0);
        vector_mul(p,f0->n,dir); vector_mul(p,p,d1);
        vector_add(pos,pos,p);
        // compute intersection edge points
        _ti=1; _tj=1;
        if (intersect_lin_ray(pnt.pnt.dat+f0->p0,pnt.pnt.dat+f0->p1,pos,dir,t)){ if (_ti) { _ti=0; ti0=t; ti1=t; } if (ti0>t) ti0=t; if (ti1<t) ti1=t; }
        if (intersect_lin_ray(pnt.pnt.dat+f0->p1,pnt.pnt.dat+f0->p2,pos,dir,t)){ if (_ti) { _ti=0; ti0=t; ti1=t; } if (ti0>t) ti0=t; if (ti1<t) ti1=t; }
        if (intersect_lin_ray(pnt.pnt.dat+f0->p2,pnt.pnt.dat+f0->p0,pos,dir,t)){ if (_ti) { _ti=0; ti0=t; ti1=t; } if (ti0>t) ti0=t; if (ti1<t) ti1=t; }
        if (intersect_lin_ray(pnt.pnt.dat+f1->p0,pnt.pnt.dat+f1->p1,pos,dir,t)){ if (_tj) { _tj=0; tj0=t; tj1=t; } if (tj0>t) tj0=t; if (tj1<t) tj1=t; }
        if (intersect_lin_ray(pnt.pnt.dat+f1->p1,pnt.pnt.dat+f1->p2,pos,dir,t)){ if (_tj) { _tj=0; tj0=t; tj1=t; } if (tj0>t) tj0=t; if (tj1<t) tj1=t; }
        if (intersect_lin_ray(pnt.pnt.dat+f1->p2,pnt.pnt.dat+f1->p0,pos,dir,t)){ if (_tj) { _tj=0; tj0=t; tj1=t; } if (tj0>t) tj0=t; if (tj1<t) tj1=t; }
        if ((_ti)||(_tj)) continue;
        if ((ti0>=tj0)&&(ti0<=tj1)) return 1;
        if ((ti1>=tj0)&&(ti1<=tj1)) return 1;
        if ((tj0>=ti0)&&(tj0<=ti1)) return 1;
        if ((tj1>=ti0)&&(tj1<=ti1)) return 1;
        }
    return 0;
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is a part of a much larger program. The `_zero` is just threshold for zero based on min detail size. `_fac3` is triangle and `_vol4` is tetrahedron. Both points and triangles are indexed from `pnt.pnt.dat[]` and `fac.dat[]` dynamic lists. I know is weird but there is a lot going on behind it (like spatial subdivision to segments and more to speed up the processes which is this used for).

the `vector_mul(a,b,c)` is `a=cross(b,c)` and `a=dot(b,c)` product (which depends on `c` if it is vector or not).

I would rather avoid any precomputed values for each triangle/tetrahedron as even now the classes holds quite a lot of info already (like parent-ship, usage count etc). And as I am bound to Win32 the memory is limited to only around `1.2 GB` so any additional stuff will limit the max size of mesh usable.

So what I am looking for is any of these:

1. **some math or coding trick to speed current approach if possible**
2. **different faster approach for this**

I am bound to **BDS2006 Win32 C++** and would rather avoid using 3th party libs.

**[Edit1] sample data**

Here is tetrahedronized pointcloud as a sample data for testing:

```
double pnt[192]=    // pnt.pnt.dat[pnt.n*3] = { x,y,z, ... }
    {
    -0.227,0.108,-0.386,
    -0.227,0.153,-0.386,
    0.227,0.108,-0.386,
    0.227,0.153,-0.386,
    0.227,0.108,-0.431,
    0.227,0.153,-0.431,
    -0.227,0.108,-0.431,
    -0.227,0.153,-0.431,
    -0.227,0.108,0.429,
    -0.227,0.153,0.429,
    0.227,0.108,0.429,
    0.227,0.153,0.429,
    0.227,0.108,0.384,
    0.227,0.153,0.384,
    -0.227,0.108,0.384,
    -0.227,0.153,0.384,
    -0.023,0.108,0.409,
    -0.023,0.153,0.409,
    0.023,0.108,0.409,
    0.023,0.153,0.409,
    0.023,0.108,-0.409,
    0.023,0.153,-0.409,
    -0.023,0.108,-0.409,
    -0.023,0.153,-0.409,
    -0.318,0.210,0.500,
    -0.318,0.233,0.500,
    0.318,0.210,0.500,
    0.318,0.233,0.500,
    0.318,0.210,-0.500,
    0.318,0.233,-0.500,
    -0.318,0.210,-0.500,
    -0.318,0.233,-0.500,
    -0.273,-0.233,0.432,
    -0.273,0.222,0.432,
    -0.227,-0.233,0.432,
    -0.227,0.222,0.432,
    -0.227,-0.233,0.386,
    -0.227,0.222,0.386,
    -0.273,-0.233,0.386,
    -0.273,0.222,0.386,
    0.227,-0.233,0.432,
    0.227,0.222,0.432,
    0.273,-0.233,0.432,
    0.273,0.222,0.432,
    0.273,-0.233,0.386,
    0.273,0.222,0.386,
    0.227,-0.233,0.386,
    0.227,0.222,0.386,
    -0.273,-0.233,-0.386,
    -0.273,0.222,-0.386,
    -0.227,-0.233,-0.386,
    -0.227,0.222,-0.386,
    -0.227,-0.233,-0.432,
    -0.227,0.222,-0.432,
    -0.273,-0.233,-0.432,
    -0.273,0.222,-0.432,
    0.227,-0.233,-0.386,
    0.227,0.222,-0.386,
    0.273,-0.233,-0.386,
    0.273,0.222,-0.386,
    0.273,-0.233,-0.432,
    0.273,0.222,-0.432,
    0.227,-0.233,-0.432,
    0.227,0.222,-0.432,
    };

struct _fac3 { int p0,p1,p2; double n[3]; };

_fac3 fac[140]= // fac.dat[fac.num] = { p0,p1,p2,n(x,y,z), ... }
    {
     78, 84, 96, 0.600,-0.800,-0.000,
     72, 84, 96, -0.844,-0.003,-0.537,
     72, 78, 84, -0.000,1.000,-0.000,
     72, 78, 96, -0.000,-0.152,0.988,
      6, 84, 96, -0.859,0.336,-0.385,
      6, 78, 96, 0.597,-0.801,0.031,
      6, 78, 84, 0.746,-0.666,0.000,
      6, 72, 96, -0.852,-0.006,-0.523,
      6, 72, 84, -0.834,0.151,-0.530,
     78, 84,147, 0.020,1.000,-0.000,
     72, 84,147, -0.023,-1.000,-0.015,
     72, 78,147, -0.000,1.000,0.014,
     78, 96,186, 0.546,-0.776,0.316,
      6, 96,186, -0.864,0.067,-0.500,
      6, 78,186, 0.995,0.014,-0.104,
     78, 84,186, 0.980,-0.201,0.000,
      6, 84,186, -0.812,0.078,-0.578,
     72, 96,186, -0.865,-0.011,-0.501,
      6, 72,186, -0.846,0.071,-0.529,
      6, 84,147, -0.153,-0.672,-0.724,
      6, 72,147, -0.222,-0.975,-0.024,
     84,135,147, 0.018,1.000,-0.013,
     78,135,147, -0.311,0.924,0.220,
     78, 84,135, 0.258,0.966,-0.000,
     72,135,147, -0.018,1.000,0.013,
     72, 78,135, -0.000,0.995,0.105,
     96,132,186, -0.000,-1.000,-0.000,
     78,132,186, 0.995,-0.087,-0.056,
     78, 96,132, 0.081,-0.256,0.963,
     84,132,186, 0.976,-0.209,-0.055,
     78, 84,132, 0.995,-0.101,0.000,
     84,147,186, -0.190,-0.111,-0.975,
      6,147,186, -0.030,-0.134,0.991,
      0, 96,186, -0.587,-0.735,-0.339,
      0, 72,186, 0.598,0.801,-0.031,
      0, 72, 96, -0.992,-0.087,-0.092,
     72,147,186, -0.675,-0.737,-0.044,
    135,147,189, 0.000,1.000,-0.000,
     84,147,189, -0.018,0.980,-0.197,
     84,135,189, 0.126,0.992,-0.007,
     81, 84,135, -0.183,0.983,-0.023,
     78, 81,135, -0.930,-0.000,0.367,
     78, 81, 84, 1.000,-0.000,0.000,
    105,135,147, -0.000,1.000,0.000,
     72,105,147, -0.126,0.992,0.007,
     72,105,135, 0.018,0.980,0.197,
     72, 81,135, -0.036,0.996,-0.082,
     72, 78, 81, -0.000,-0.000,1.000,
     96,120,132, -0.000,-1.000,-0.000,
     78,120,132, 0.685,-0.246,0.685,
     78, 96,120, -0.000,-0.152,0.988,
    132,180,186, -0.000,-1.000,0.000,
     84,180,186, 0.000,-0.152,-0.988,
     84,132,180, 0.995,-0.101,-0.000,
    147,150,186, 0.101,0.010,0.995,
     84,150,186, -0.100,-0.131,-0.986,
     84,147,150, -0.190,-0.019,-0.982,
     96,114,186, 0.000,-1.000,0.000,
      0,114,186, -0.584,-0.729,-0.357,
      0, 96,114, -0.991,0.134,0.000,
      0,147,186, -0.144,-0.058,-0.988,
      0, 72,147, -0.926,-0.374,-0.052,
     72, 96,114, -0.995,-0.101,0.000,
      0, 72,114, -0.993,-0.077,-0.093,
     75,147,189, -0.001,1.000,-0.012,
     75,135,189, 0.018,1.000,-0.001,
     75,135,147, -0.016,-1.000,0.012,
    147,159,189, -0.000,1.000,-0.000,
     84,159,189, -0.000,0.985,-0.174,
     84,147,159, -0.025,-0.999,-0.025,
     81,135,189, -0.274,0.962,0.015,
     81, 84,189, 0.114,0.993,-0.023,
     75,105,147, -0.115,-0.993,0.006,
     75,105,135, 0.017,-0.983,0.181,
     72, 75,147, -0.999,-0.000,-0.051,
     72, 75,105, 0.599,-0.000,0.801,
     81,105,135, -0.009,0.996,-0.093,
     72, 81,105, -0.036,0.991,0.127,
    120,126,132, -0.000,-1.000,-0.000,
     78,126,132, 0.995,-0.101,-0.000,
     78,120,126, -0.000,-0.152,0.988,
      0,150,186, 0.101,-0.000,0.995,
      0,147,150, -0.000,-0.000,1.000,
    144,150,186, 0.000,-1.000,0.000,
     84,144,186, -0.091,-0.133,-0.987,
     84,144,150, -0.000,0.249,0.968,
    147,150,159, -0.705,-0.071,-0.705,
     84,150,159, -0.125,-0.100,-0.987,
    114,150,186, 0.000,-1.000,0.000,
      0,114,150, -0.998,-0.000,-0.059,
     72,114,147, -0.995,-0.088,-0.052,
      0,114,147, -0.906,-0.365,-0.215,
     93,147,189, -0.009,-0.996,-0.093,
     75, 93,189, 0.020,1.000,0.000,
     75, 93,147, -0.237,-0.971,-0.000,
     75, 81,189, -0.000,1.000,-0.012,
     75, 81,135, -0.000,-0.995,0.096,
     93,159,189, -0.000,-0.987,-0.160,
     93,147,159, -0.069,-0.995,-0.069,
     84, 93,189, 0.036,0.991,-0.127,
     84, 93,159, -0.036,-0.993,-0.113,
     84, 87,189, -0.599,-0.000,-0.801,
     81, 87,189, -0.120,0.993,-0.000,
     81, 84, 87, 1.000,0.000,0.000,
     75, 81,105, -0.000,-0.987,0.160,
     72, 93,147, -0.183,-0.983,-0.023,
     72, 75, 93, -1.000,0.000,-0.000,
     72, 75, 81, 0.000,-0.000,1.000,
    114,147,150, -0.993,-0.100,-0.059,
    144,162,186, 0.000,-1.000,0.000,
     84,162,186, -0.000,-0.152,-0.988,
     84,144,162, -0.600,0.800,0.000,
    144,150,159, 0.000,0.101,0.995,
     84,144,159, -0.125,-0.087,-0.988,
    144,147,159, -0.707,0.000,-0.707,
    144,147,150, -0.000,0.000,1.000,
     93,114,147, 0.732,-0.587,-0.346,
     72, 93,114, -0.995,-0.100,-0.002,
     81, 93,189, 0.022,1.000,-0.014,
     75, 81, 93, -0.000,1.000,0.000,
     93,144,159, 0.582,-0.140,-0.801,
     93,144,147, -0.930,0.000,0.367,
     87, 93,189, -0.000,0.987,0.160,
     84, 87, 93, -0.000,0.000,-1.000,
     84, 93,144, -0.009,-0.238,-0.971,
     81, 87, 93, -0.000,1.000,0.000,
    114,144,150, -0.000,-1.000,-0.000,
    114,144,147, -1.000,0.000,-0.000,
     93,144,162, -0.995,-0.096,0.000,
     84, 93,162, -0.005,-0.145,-0.989,
     93,114,144, -0.995,-0.096,0.000,
     72,114,144, -0.995,-0.101,-0.000,
     72, 93,144, -0.995,-0.097,-0.002,
     90,144,162, -0.995,-0.101,0.000,
     90, 93,162, 0.834,0.000,-0.552,
     90, 93,144, -0.930,0.000,0.367,
     84, 90,162, 0.000,-0.152,-0.988,
     84, 90, 93, 0.000,0.000,-1.000,
     72, 90,144, -0.995,-0.101,-0.000,
     72, 90, 93, -1.000,0.000,-0.000,
    };

struct _vol4 { int p0,p1,p2,p3,t[4]; double s[4]; };

_vol4 vol[62]=  // vol.dat[vol.num] = { p0,p1,p2,p3,t[0],t[1],t[2],t[3],s[0],s[1],s[2],s[3], ... }
    {
     72, 78, 96, 84,   0,  1,  2,  3, 1,1,1,1,
     78, 84, 96,  6,   4,  5,  6,  0, 1,1,1,-1,
     72, 84, 96,  6,   4,  7,  8,  1, -1,1,1,-1,
     72, 78, 84,147,   9, 10, 11,  2, 1,1,1,-1,
      6, 78, 96,186,  12, 13, 14,  5, 1,1,1,-1,
      6, 78, 84,186,  15, 16, 14,  6, 1,1,-1,-1,
      6, 72, 96,186,  17, 13, 18,  7, 1,-1,1,-1,
      6, 72, 84,147,  10, 19, 20,  8, -1,1,1,-1,
     78, 84,147,135,  21, 22, 23,  9, 1,1,1,-1,
     72, 78,147,135,  22, 24, 25, 11, -1,1,1,-1,
     78, 96,186,132,  26, 27, 28, 12, 1,1,1,-1,
     78, 84,186,132,  29, 27, 30, 15, 1,-1,1,-1,
      6, 84,186,147,  31, 32, 19, 16, 1,1,-1,-1,
     72, 96,186,  0,  33, 34, 35, 17, 1,1,1,-1,
      6, 72,186,147,  36, 32, 20, 18, 1,-1,-1,-1,
     84,135,147,189,  37, 38, 39, 21, 1,1,1,-1,
     78, 84,135, 81,  40, 41, 42, 23, 1,1,1,-1,
     72,135,147,105,  43, 44, 45, 24, 1,1,1,-1,
     72, 78,135, 81,  41, 46, 47, 25, -1,1,1,-1,
     78, 96,132,120,  48, 49, 50, 28, 1,1,1,-1,
     84,132,186,180,  51, 52, 53, 29, 1,1,1,-1,
     84,147,186,150,  54, 55, 56, 31, 1,1,1,-1,
      0, 96,186,114,  57, 58, 59, 33, 1,1,1,-1,
      0, 72,186,147,  36, 60, 61, 34, -1,1,1,-1,
      0, 72, 96,114,  62, 59, 63, 35, 1,-1,1,-1,
    135,147,189, 75,  64, 65, 66, 37, 1,1,1,-1,
     84,147,189,159,  67, 68, 69, 38, 1,1,1,-1,
     84,135,189, 81,  70, 71, 40, 39, 1,1,-1,-1,
    105,135,147, 75,  66, 72, 73, 43, -1,1,1,-1,
     72,105,147, 75,  72, 74, 75, 44, -1,1,1,-1,
     72,105,135, 81,  76, 46, 77, 45, 1,-1,1,-1,
     78,120,132,126,  78, 79, 80, 49, 1,1,1,-1,
    147,150,186,  0,  81, 60, 82, 54, 1,-1,1,-1,
     84,150,186,144,  83, 84, 85, 55, 1,1,1,-1,
     84,147,150,159,  86, 87, 69, 56, 1,1,-1,-1,
      0,114,186,150,  88, 81, 89, 58, 1,-1,1,-1,
      0, 72,147,114,  90, 91, 63, 61, 1,1,-1,-1,
     75,147,189, 93,  92, 93, 94, 64, 1,1,1,-1,
     75,135,189, 81,  70, 95, 96, 65, -1,1,1,-1,
    147,159,189, 93,  97, 92, 98, 67, 1,-1,1,-1,
     84,159,189, 93,  97, 99,100, 68, -1,1,1,-1,
     81, 84,189, 87, 101,102,103, 71, 1,1,1,-1,
     75,105,135, 81,  76, 96,104, 73, -1,-1,1,-1,
     72, 75,147, 93,  94,105,106, 74, -1,1,1,-1,
     72, 75,105, 81, 104, 77,107, 75, -1,-1,1,-1,
      0,147,150,114, 108, 89, 91, 82, 1,-1,-1,-1,
     84,144,186,162, 109,110,111, 84, 1,1,1,-1,
     84,144,150,159, 112, 87,113, 85, 1,-1,1,-1,
    147,150,159,144, 112,114,115, 86, -1,1,1,-1,
     72,114,147, 93, 116,105,117, 90, 1,-1,1,-1,
     75, 93,189, 81, 118, 95,119, 93, 1,-1,1,-1,
     93,147,159,144, 114,120,121, 98, -1,1,1,-1,
     84, 93,189, 87, 122,101,123, 99, 1,-1,1,-1,
     84, 93,159,144, 120,113,124,100, -1,-1,1,-1,
     81, 87,189, 93, 122,118,125,102, -1,-1,1,-1,
    114,147,150,144, 115,126,127,108, -1,1,1,-1,
     84,144,162, 93, 128,129,124,111, 1,1,-1,-1,
     93,114,147,144, 127,121,130,116, -1,-1,1,-1,
     72, 93,114,144, 130,131,132,117, -1,1,1,-1,
     93,144,162, 90, 133,134,135,128, 1,1,1,-1,
     84, 93,162, 90, 134,136,137,129, -1,1,1,-1,
     72, 93,144, 90, 135,138,139,132, -1,1,1,-1,
    };
```

the `p?` are point indexes `0,3,6,9...` from `pnt` the `n` is normal `s` is sign of normal (in case triangle is shared so normals point the same way) and `t[4]` are indexes of triangles `0,1,2,3,...` from `fac`.
And here a sample test:

```
bool tetrahedrons::vols_intersect()                     // test if vol[] intersects each other
    {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<vol.num;i++)
     for (j=i+1;j<vol.num;j++,dbg_cnt++)
      if (intersect_vol_vol(vol.dat[i],vol.dat[j]))
        {
        linc=0x800000FF;
        if (intersect_vol_vol(vol.dat[j],vol.dat[i])) linc=0x8000FFFF;
        lin_add_vol(vol.dat[i]);
        lin_add_vol(vol.dat[j]);
        return 1;
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

where `dbg_cnt` is counter of intersection tests. For this mesh I got this results:

```
tests | time
------+-------------
18910 | 190-215 [ms]
```

I called the `vols_intersect` test 10 times to make the measurements long enough. Of coarse none of placed tetrahedrons in this dataset will intersect (leading to highest time). In the real process (too big to post) which lead to this mesh are the count like this:

```
intersecting        5
non intersecting 1766
all tests        1771
```

Comment: Have you tried Separating axes method? It is rather fast (you have only 8 axes). https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MethodOfSeparatingAxes.pdf

Comment: it is used for something similar to quick hull so any newly added tetrahedron can intersect none some or even all of the tetrahedrons already placed. But none of the tetrahedrons already placed are intersecting

Comment: This is merely a hunch - but have you considered Dirk Gregorius' [modified SAT algorithm](https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1017646/Physics-for-Game-Programmers-The)? There's a sample implementation of it on [GitHub](https://github.com/irlanrobson/bounce_lite/tree/master/Src/Collision).

Comment: @Spektre Are you sure that your algorithm covers all corner cases (like parallel faces and the case where one tetrahedron is completely enclosed in the other)? I am a bit doubting. Your approach is already very similar to the Separating Axis Test that MBo suggested and I would recommend going there. However ...

Comment: @MBo ... you will need 24 tests for SAT-testing two tetrahedra: 4 normals of the first tetrahedron, 4 normals of the second tetrahedron, and 16 cross products of all normal pairs from both tetrahedra that account for separation by edges.

Comment: This paper discuss a possibility to diminish number of operations: http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/Publications/2003/GPR03/fast_tetrahedron_tetrahedron_overlap_algorithm.pdf

Comment: @YvesDaoust hmm that would be very hard to compile together ... what about some sample pointcloud tetrahedron-ized and test all the surface tetrahedron against some randomly generated ones that should get as close to the real thing as I can think of but will take me time to compile/bust it together

Comment: @NicoSchertler do not think so but that is not a problem as such placement is valid in my case (and can be avoided easily by simple placement rule) I just do not need to touch/intersect the sides except fully sharing it.The SAT is almost the same the only difference I see is in the final test stage where instead of 24 tests I go with 6 different ones.

Comment: @YvesDaoust oow you want just number not a dataset :) I just  created a sample ASCII export ... will edit it into question soon I need to check if I did not do some silly-ness first

Comment: What is required is the total count of the tests for intersection performed, the count of tests that conclude no intersection, and the count of tests that conclude no intersection just by the bounding box (or bounding sphere) test.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I removed the bbox and bsphere tests  as they only slowed things down no point to add/measure them ....